# Fraction Frenzy!

Tags: code-golf, math, rational-numbers

*EDIT: I'm getting a lot of comments about this not terminating - I will give the "correct answer" tag to either the first person who gives me `FF(3)` (as in provides it in their answer) or proves that `FF(3)` does indeed blow up indefinitely.*

### Task:

Your task is make the smallest program possible that generates the list of reciprocals of the Fraction Frenzy function (`FF(n)`) given a positive integer `n`.

### Introduction:

Before I can introduce the FF function, I have to first explain Egyptian fractions.

#### Egyptian Fractions:

Egyptian fractions are a way of expressing fractions as the sum of distinct unit fractions - so one way to express the fraction `5/8` is `1/2 + 1/8`. It is not other fraction sums like

```
1/4 + 1/4 + 1/8
1/2 + 1/16 + 1/16
```

because not all of their fractions are distinct (`1/4` is repeated in the first example, and `1/16` in the second).

In our definition of Egyptian fractions, we are including the use of negative denominators in the unit fractions as well.

#### FF function:

The FF (Fraction Frenzy) function is described like so:

`FF(1)` is the Egyptian fraction `1/2 + 1/3 + 1/5 + 1/-30`.

`FF(2)` is equal to `FF(1)` "multiplied" by itself (`FF(1)` "squared"):

```
  (1/2 + 1/3 + 1/5 + 1/-30)(1/2 + 1/3 + 1/5 + 1/-30)
= 1/4 + 1/6 + 1/10 + 1/-60 + 1/6 + 1/9 + 1/15 + 1/-90 +
  1/10 + 1/15 + 1/25 + 1/-150 + 1/-60 + 1/-90 + 1/-150 + 1/900
```

This is not a fully reduced Egyptian fraction yet, because there are "repeats" in fractions. To reduce them, the following procedure is done:

1. Sum all "like" unit fractions together.
2. Reduce the sums to their simplest forms - so for example, if a sum from step `1` is `2/6`, that can be reduced to `1/3`.
3. Repeat 1 and 2 until all denominators are distinct: for example, `1/2 + 2/3 + 1/5`, as opposed to `1/2 + 1/3 + 1/3`, which has a repeating denominator `3`.
4. If there is a pair of one positive and one negative fraction that have an equal absolute value, remove both of them (e.g. `1/-5` and `1/5` must both be removed).
5. If fractions are not unit and cannot be reduced further, split it up into unit fractions with a equal denominator, and keep one fraction as it is. With the other ones, multiply them by `FF(1)`: `(1/2 + 1/3 + 1/5 + 1/-30)`.
6. Repeat steps 1-5 until the final fraction sum is a valid Egyptian fraction - i.e. all fractions are distinct from one another, and they are all unit fractions.

This is the reduction of `FF(2)`:

```
  1/4 + 1/6 + 1/10 + 1/-60 + 1/6 + 1/9 + 1/15 + 1/-90 +
  1/10 + 1/15 + 1/25 + 1/-150 + 1/-60 + 1/-90 + 1/-150 + 1/900
= 1/4 + 2/6 + 1/9 + 2/10 + 2/15 + 1/25 + 2/-60 + 2/-90 + 2/-150 + 1/900 (step 1)
= 1/4 + 1/3 + 1/9 + 1/5 + 2/15 + 1/25 + 1/-30 + 1/-45 + 1/-75 + 1/900   (step 2)
= 1/3 + 1/4 + 1/5 + 1/9 + 1/15 + 1/15(1/2 + 1/3 + 1/5 + 1/-30) +        (step 5)
  1/25 + 1/-30 + 1/-45 + 1/-75 + 1/900
= 1/3 + 1/4 + 1/5 + 1/9 + 1/15 + 1/30 + 1/45 + 1/75 + 1/-450 +
  1/25 + 1/-30 + 1/-45 + 1/-75 + 1/900
= 1/3 + 1/4 + 1/5 + 1/9 + 1/15 + 1/25 + 1/-450 + 1/900                  (step 4)
```

For all `n` (except for `1`), `FF(n)` is defined by "squaring" `FF(n-1)`.

### Input and Output:

Given an integer `n`, you must output a list all of the reciprocals of `FF(n)`, sorted in ascending order of their absolute values:

```
1 -> [2, 3, 5, -30]
# 1/2 + 1/3 + 1/5 + 1/-30 = FF(1), reciprocals = [2, 3, 5, -30]

2 -> [3, 4, 5, 9, 15, 25, -450, 900]
```

You are allowed to use a string with any delimiter, or your language's interpretation of a list, so these outputs are all acceptable with the input `1`:

```
2 3 5 -30   (Space-delimited)
2,3,5,-30   (Comma-delimited)
[2 3 5 -30] (Lisp-like lists)
etc. etc.
```

### Specs:

- You must output the results of the `FF(n)` function exactly as specified above.
- You are guaranteed that the input will be a positive integer - it will never be below zero, and it will never be a decimal (or fraction).

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest code in bytes wins!

Comment: Out of curiosity, is this guaranteed to terminate?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53236/discussion-between-qwerp-derp-and-martin-ender).

Comment: I confirm that FF(3) seems to blow up. Did you not test this up to about FF(10) before posting to the sandbox?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53238/discussion-between-qwerp-derp-and-peter-taylor).

Comment: `until all reciprocals are distinct` -- Can you clarify what this means?

Comment: `until the final fraction sum is a valid Egyptian fraction` -- This too. The example suggests that step 4 has to be applied again if it causes a change, even though that's not part of the stated definition of an Egyptian fraction. Maybe you mean "*until it doesn't change anymore*", in both cases?

Comment: F(3) doesn't appear to terminate for me, either. [See here](https://gist.github.com/smls/4f132878ce90ee4658e0f1bcb665d2bc) for my non-golfed program and its debug output, written under the assumption that we need to iterate until it doesn't change anymore.

Comment: Egyptian fractions didn't have negative values in them, so it's not really an Egyptian fraction.

Comment: @mbomb007 Fixed as well.

Comment: @smls Finished editing for both of your queries.

Comment: I think step 6, as written, still doesn't explain why step 4 (canceling out negatives) is performed at the end of the reduction of `FF(2)`, since the result of previous step 5 already consisted of distinct unit fractions - just not with distinct *absolute values*.

Comment: @smls Yeah... didn't put that in, nice catch.

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 365 bytes

```hs
import Data.Function;import Data.List;import Data.Ratio;n=numerator;d=denominator
r=until=<<((==)=<<)$filter(/=0).map(sum).groupBy((==)`on`d).sortBy(compare`on`d)
p s=let(o,q)=span((<2).abs.n)s in case q of []->o;(a:b)->let j=a-1%d a*signum a in p.r$o++[a-j]++map(*j)e++b
s s=(*)<$>s<*>s;e=(1%)<$>[2,3,5,-30];f=iterate(p.r.s)e;o i=[abs(d q)*signum(n q)|q<-f!!(i-1)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/haskell#VU87T8MwEN77K1yple7yME1LFxJnQIgJFtYootfGqVw1tmM7AxL/vTjAANPdffped1ODNS6wJwrEnyd9Csro8i/4onz4B7xR5JRa6GmQjoJxZSc6qc2g9HwtnJh0UFdRVQBCYJy46tU1SAd3YoN8IAt@GpCfnZns48c362D0oUPuY0pETmaw5OQPuLDMi6sMYLIRhbekAaotcjp6rtEzpdmJvGQjMz1r2rw2JdDDEfM6ithFUF6sO0aJV@dYmdEssNytTJo2lF/aNJ0bJReUaXpc@BgGCVar2ldJ7UspoFjPZ7PNdtk@y3ebtuyFCvPvEqIR9yhLw5RoYiPo2Ii/UaDj/jlWeb9cgsoLbG8DKS1i3Os7WKd04AabIpud77N9e/sC)

Comment: Hmm… i run into an apparently infinite loop when splitting the largest non-unit and rechecking at a time as presented and had already done so when splitting the smallest non-unit in leftwards reverse or globally all non-units before rechecking but perhaps i should not fail to nondeterministically pick non-units from in between whether one cancels out enough others to reach a finite FF(3)?

Comment: Using `(1%)<$>[2,4,6,12]` as 1 merely procrastinates the nontermination from FF(3) to FF(4) 

Comment: `(1%)<$>[2,3,10,15]` or `(1%)<$>[3,4,6,8,12,24]` yield no improvement at all 